# How to get rolling 7 day total on dates by groups?

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime, dplyr, databricks

I want to create a `total_dose` variable that continues to add up the values in the `dosage` variable. Once the `dosage` is 7 days old, it is subtracted from the `total_dose` variable.

This process continues on a rolling basis. I want code so that the total_dose count starts again when the `pid` or `medname` changes.

Dummy dataset:

```
  pid    medname    date              route     dosage  
1  1     drugA    2023-04-15 17:30:00 patch     30      
2  1     drugA    2023-04-16 11:45:00 patch     30      
3  1     drugA    2023-04-17 10:30:00 patch     30      
4  2     drugB    2023-04-27 22:00:00 patch     30      
5  2     drugB    2023-04-30 13:15:00 patch     30      
6  2     drugB    2023-05-10 13:15:00 patch     30      
7  2     drugA    2023-05-11 06:30:00 patch     30
```

Desired output

```
  pid    medname    date              route     dosage   total_dose
1  1     drugA    2023-04-15 17:30:00 patch     30       30
2  1     drugA    2023-04-16 11:45:00 patch     30       60
3  1     drugA    2023-04-17 10:30:00 patch     30       90
4  2     drugB    2023-04-27 22:00:00 patch     30       30
5  2     drugB    2023-04-30 13:15:00 patch     30       60
6  2     drugB    2023-05-10 13:15:00 patch     30       30
7  2     drugA    2023-05-11 06:30:00 patch     30       30
```

The code that has been attempted:

```
df2 <- transform(df1, total_dosage = ave(dosage, list(pid, medname,
                      cumsum(c(0, diff(as.numeric(date - date[1]))) > 604800)), 
                 FUN = cumsum))
```

Using with a `group_by` function:

```
df2 <- df1 %>% 
  group_by(pid, medname) %>% 
  arrange(date, .by_group = TRUE) 

df3 <- transform(df2,
        total_dose = ave(dose, cumsum(c(0, diff(as.numeric(date - date[1]))) > 604800), 
                 FUN=cumsum))
```

Further attempt when using `group_by`:

```
df2 <- df1 %>% 
  group_by(pid, medname) %>% 
  arrange(date, .by_group = TRUE) 

df3 <- transform(df2, 
            time_since_first_dose = cumsum(c(0, diff(as.numeric(date - date[1])))), 
            group_change = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(pid) != 0 | diff(medname) != 0)), 
            total_dose = ave(dosage, group_change, time_since_first_dose, FUN=cumsum))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a one-liner using 604,800 seconds of a week.

```
transform(df, total_dose=ave(dosage, cumsum(c(0, diff(as.numeric(date - date[1]))) > 604800), FUN=cumsum))
#                  date route dosage total_dose
# 1 2023-04-15 17:30:00 patch     30         30
# 2 2023-04-16 11:45:00 patch     30         60
# 3 2023-04-17 10:30:00 patch     30         90
# 4 2023-04-30 22:00:00 patch     30         30
# 5 2023-05-10 13:15:00 patch     30         30
# 6 2023-05-11 06:30:00 patch     30         60
```

No extra packages used.

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(date = c("2023-04-15 17:30:00", "2023-04-16 11:45:00", 
"2023-04-17 10:30:00", "2023-04-30 22:00:00", "2023-05-10 13:15:00", 
"2023-05-11 06:30:00"), route = c("patch", "patch", "patch", 
"patch", "patch", "patch"), dosage = c("30", "30", "30", "30", 
"30", "30")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

df$date <- as.POSIXct(df$date)
```

Comment: Thank you for the script, it works great on the dummy set and on my actual data.  How would I adjust this script to add variables (pid, medname) using group_by(pid, medname) to restart the total_dose count when either of these new variables change.

Comment: @db2020 I use `ave` instead of `dplyr::group by`, just add more grouping factors in `ave`, see `?ave`. Cheers!

Comment: I have tried adding the additional grouping using ave, however, it gives the following error... 'Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1790.5 Gb'. Seems to be a memory issue. So I thought using group_by may get around this memory issue. I have updated my above question with the amended desired output using your suggested code as a base.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  mutate(date = mdy_hm(date), 
         dosage = 30,
         grp = consecutive_id(pid, medname)) %>% 
  mutate(diff_time = difftime(date, lag(date), units = "days"),
         dose_tmp = if_else(is.na(diff_time) | diff_time < 7, 1, -1),
         total_dose = cumsum(dose_tmp * dosage),
         .by = grp) %>% 
  select(-c(dose_tmp, diff_time, grp))
```

```
  pid medname                date route dosage total_dose
1   1   drugA 2023-04-15 17:30:00 patch     30         30
2   1   drugA 2023-04-16 11:45:00 patch     30         60
3   1   drugA 2023-04-17 10:30:00 patch     30         90
4   2   drugB 2023-04-27 22:00:00 patch     30         30
5   2   drugB 2023-04-30 13:15:00 patch     30         60
6   2   drugB 2023-05-10 13:15:00 patch     30         30
7   2   drugA 2023-05-11 06:30:00 patch     30         30
```